# Hex to bin after logical operations

Tags: c, casting, hex

I want:

```
111 || 100  ---> 111,  not 1
100 && 100  ---> 100,  not 1
101 && 010  ---> 000,  not 0
```

**Broken code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(void){
        string hexa = 0xff;
        strig hexa2 = 0xf1;

        // CONVERT TO INT??? cast
        int hexa3 = hexa || hexa2;
        int hexa4 = hexa && hexa2;

        puts(hexa3);
        puts(hexa4);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want the bitwise operators (`|`, `&`) instead of the logical operators (`||`, `&&`):

```
110 | 011 --> 111
110 & 101 --> 100
```

As for your broken code, you also have incorrect types for `hexa` and `hexb` which should both be numeric types:

```
int hexa = 0xff;
int hexa2 = 0xf1;
```

Finally, to output an integer, you would use `printf` to format them:

```
printf("hexa3 = 0x%08x\n", heaxa3);   // display as 8 digit, 0 padded hex
```

Comment: || and && are binary operators, too. I think you meant to say "bit-wise".

Comment: @sepp2k - thanks, I'm much better with remembering how the features work and not their correct name

Comment: @user355926 | and & return full binary

Comment: Can you use terminal's printf in a similar way?

Comment: When performing bit manipulations, prefer `unsigned int` to `int`.  The `unsigned int` lets you play with all the bits and not have to deal with sign extensions.

Answer (score 1):

1. `string` is not the right data type here. There is a big difference between the number 0xff (which is 11111111 in binary) and the string "0xff." I'm assuming you want to deal with the former; parsing strings into integers is an entire topic of its own. One good data type for a sequence of 16 bits is `unsigned int`.
2. There is a big difference between || and |. The former does a so-called "logical" or: it converts both operands to a boolean and then return true if at least one of the operands is true, and false otherwise. A operand is converted into false if it is 0, true otherwise. Thus, for your example, 0xff and 0xf1 are both converted to true, and true || true == true. This is why your code prints 1.

Side note: even for booleans, || and | are different, because of short-circuiting: when you have `a || b`, b is only evaluated if a is false. Both arguments are evaluated for `a | b`. This matters, i.e., when one of the two operands is a function call with side-effects.